# Get details about "Remote UNIX connection disconnected"

Tags: asterisk

I am getting lots of:

```
-- Remote UNIX connection disconnected
```

I would like to get more details about it. How do I get information about who is connecting, ip address, and more details?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a GUI like FreePBX installed. Correct?

These messages happen whenever the GUI connects to the backend asterisk processes to change configuration, get status updates, etc.

Comment: No FreePBX. And I know about this messages. I was just getting *way* to many (like 3 msg/s), and wanted to verify who was doing this.